# UI given by static library doesnt support device orientations

Tags: ios, static-libraries, device-orientation

I am using a static library in my ios app which gives me a UI through which a user can be authenticated.

this static library,  does not support any rotations of the device.

I got the source of the library and I have included the statement

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return YES;
}
```

in its viewcontroller that generates the UI.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Describe what happens when you rotate the device. Please be detailed.

Comment: when I rotate the device the UI rotates with the device and does not align itself according to the orientation of the device. Can please help me out what details you need ?

Answer (score 0):

Open the .xib file in Interface Builder and use struts and springs or auto layout to adjust the alignment and spacing. If those don't provide enough control for you to get the desired layout, you'll need to add some code to pin things at runtime.

Comment: the library doesn't provide any xib files. all the UI is developed programatically only.

Comment: can you please provide some hints like what needs to be done to handle this.

Comment: I think the issue is that the event of device orientation changing does not reaches the view controller defined in the static library.